# Using python, how can i check if a html checkbox is hidden, and if it's checked?

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, checkbox

In an HTML form, I have a checkbox which class is 'hidden' or not, depending on the user's previous choices.

This is my HTML javascript code which creates the checkbox

```
const cityBusesLabel = document.createElement('label');
cityBusesLabel.textContent = `Use of city buses`;
const cityBusesInput = document.createElement('input');
cityBusesInput.type = 'checkbox';
cityBusesInput.name = `cityBuses ${venueNumber}-${originCounter}`;
cityBusesInput.id = `cityBusesInput ${venueNumber}-${originCounter}`;
cityBusesInput.classList.add('hidden');
cityBusesLabel.id = `cityBusesLabel ${venueNumber}-${originCounter}`;
cityBusesLabel.classList.add('hidden');
cityBusesLabel.appendChild(cityBusesInput);
```

And this is the HTML javascript code that shows / hides it :

```
document.getElementById('venue_location_' + venueNumber).addEventListener('input', function() { 
    const select_value = document.getElementById('venue_location_' + venueNumber).value;
    if (select_value === 'suburban') {
        document.getElementById('cityBusesInput ' + venueNumber + '-' + originCounter).classList.remove('hidden');
        document.getElementById('cityBusesLabel ' + venueNumber + '-' + originCounter).classList.remove('hidden');
    } else {
        document.getElementById('cityBusesInput ' + venueNumber + '-' + originCounter).classList.add('hidden');
        document.getElementById('cityBusesLabel ' + venueNumber + '-' + originCounter).classList.add('hidden');
    }
});
```

Now, in my app.py python code using Flask, I am trying to check first of all if the checkbox is hidden or not, and second of all if it's checked or not.

I tried writing :

```
cityBuses_checkbox = request.form.get(f'cityBuses {i}-{origin_counter}')
if cityBuses_checkbox :
    if cityBuses_checkbox == 'on' :
         city_buses.append(1)
    else :
         city_buses.append(0)
```

But it didn't give me the output I wanted. Is this the right way to do these two checks?

Comment: Unchecked boxes are not sent, `form.get(...)` -> `None`. The hidden class will not be sent at all since it is not data. Relying on userside/javascript is not safe, the server should decide how to handle the data depending on the submitted data.